# Inner Join in Codeigniter with multiple table

Tags: codeigniter

I wants to create a display function in crudodel of codeigniter to display records on Invoice no 13. I'd run the bellow Query on sql. Its working as per my requirement. Now I've to convert this Query in codeigniter using Inner Join.

```sql
SELECT b1.Invoice_No,
       cust_name,
       cust_address,
       cust_contact,
       Item_name,
       Item_qty,
       Item_amount
FROM tbl_bill_invoice AS b1
INNER JOIN tbl_billmenu AS b2 ON(b2.Invoice_No = b1.Invoice_No)
INNER JOIN tbl_billcustomer AS b3 ON(b3.cust_id = b1.cust_id)
WHERE b1.Invoice_no = 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('b1.Invoice_No, cust_name, cust_address, cust_contact, Item_name, Item_qty, Item_amount');
$this->db->from(' tbl_bill_invoice as b1');
$this->db->join('tbl_billmenu as b2', 'b2.Invoice_No = b1.Invoice_No', 'inner');
$this->db->join('tbl_billcustomer as b3', 'b3.cust_id = b1.cust_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('b1.Invoice_no', 13);
return $this->db->get()->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look,

```
$invoice_no = 13;
$this->db->select('b1.Invoice_No, cust_name, cust_address, cust_contact, Item_name, Item_qty, Item_amount');
$this->db->from('tbl_bill_invoice b1');
$this->db->join('tbl_billmenu b2', 'b2.Invoice_No = b1.Invoice_No', 'inner');
$this->db->join('tbl_billcustomer b3', 'b3.cust_id = b1.cust_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('b1.Invoice_no', $invoice_no);
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->row();
} else {
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write this

```
$sql = "SELECT b1.Invoice_No,
   cust_name,
   cust_address,
   cust_contact,
   Item_name,
   Item_qty,
   Item_amount
   FROM tbl_bill_invoice AS b1
   INNER JOIN tbl_billmenu AS b2 ON(b2.Invoice_No = b1.Invoice_No)
   INNER JOIN tbl_billcustomer AS b3 ON(b3.cust_id = b1.cust_id)
   WHERE b1.Invoice_no = 13";
$result = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```